# Simple question on pointers and how to initialize an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a question on a simple program that i wrote to initialize an array one element at a time, the few lines of code are below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *ptr;
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        ptr[index]=index;
        printf("%d\n", ptr[index]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

All plain and simple but when I run the program I incur in segmentation fault (core dumped) error, that to my understanding occurs when you try to write on something that is only readeable or if you have exceeded your allowed memory...
Excuse me for this probably nobbish question but I could not find a similar question on SO.

Comment: You haven't allocated any space to your array.  You will want to use `malloc` or `calloc`, and then use `free` when you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys, really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just use `int *ptr` and treat it as an array. You need to actually create an array and allocate space for it, by specifying the size. You can either make it as an array like in the first option, or allocate it using `malloc()` in the second option. I suggest the first one because it executes faster, and it seems your array is of fixed length. The second option is for applications where you do not know the array size until runtime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int ptr[4]; //you need to specify array size first
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        ptr[index]=index;
        printf("%d\n", ptr[index]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use `malloc()` if you want to allocate it on the heap, but make sure to `free()` it, to free the memory, or there will be a memory leak.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 4; index++)
    {
        ptr[index]=index;
        printf("%d\n", ptr[index]);
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This should solve your problem

Also you don't need a for loop to initialize populate the values of the array, in case that is what you are trying to do. You can do this:

```
int ptr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and for the detailed answer, It has been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @ChristianGibbons comment, you just need to allocate memory for the array the address of your pointer.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
    int sizeOfArray = 4;
    int *ptr = calloc(sizeOfArray, sizeof(int)); // line to fix
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < sizeOfArray; index++)
        {
        ptr[index]=index;
        printf("%d\n", ptr[index]);
        }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `malloc` in this example since the data is going to be initialized in the loop anyways.

Comment: You forgot to free it

Comment: @Asadefa whoops, I'll add that :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did choose Asadefa one because it's the first that I read but I have given ups to yours too. Thanks again!

Comment: Also if it is constant in size, it can just be stack memory as it is faster